# FTP in PHP not copy index.php file

Tags: php, apache, ftp, indexing, warnings

I have a PHP script to copy all files in a directory i have change my server now its not copying index.php file all other files copy successfully and throw bellow warnings.

```
Warning: ftp_get(tmp/readme.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/Site.com/httpdocs/includes/ftp.class.php on line 123

Warning: ftp_get(): Error opening tmp/readme.txt in /var/www/vhosts/Site.com/httpdocs/includes/ftp.class.php on line 123

Warning: fopen(tmp/readme.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/Site.com/httpdocs/includes/clone.php on line 196
```

Comment: To answer your questions in comments below: Each file on your server will have its own set of permissions. You might have permission to read one file in a directory but not another.

Comment: I am copying files from ftp1 to ftp2 and ftp1 files have ftp1 user rights and ftp2 files has ftp2 user rights all other files copied successfully only index.php file didn't copy on destination (ftp2) if of ftp2 there is any thing written in index.php file and when i run the script it remove all content from the destination and make it empty.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a permission issue on the new server. Double check the server directory you're accessing to make sure, you and apache have the appropriate permissions.

Comment: If this is a permission then how other files can copied and directories created on the destination only `index.php` file could not copy on destination.

Comment: Try to recreate the index file. Just a copy of course, and verify the permissions on that one file. I'm not sure exactly what your environment set up is like, but the error message states is a permission problem.

Comment: I am copying files from ftp1 to ftp2 and ftp1 files have ftp1 user rights and ftp2 files has ftp2 user rights all other files copied successfully only index.php file didn't copy on destination (ftp2) if of ftp2 there is any thing written in index.php file and when i run the script it remove all content from the destination and make it empty.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message says: Permission denied, in other words your script does not have permission to access the file tmp/readme.txt. Check that the user your PHP script is using has read access to the file/folder. The way to check that depends on what your server setup is so can't give more unless you provide more info about what your server is running.

Comment: If this is a permission then how other files can copied and directories created on the destination only `index.php` file could not copy on destination.  `tmp/readme.txt` file copy sucessfully.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the unix world. It is a permission problem. If you have rights, you can fix it with the command chmod in the server.

```
 $ ssh username@server
 $ chmod PERMISSIONS /path/to/filr
```

check the man page of chmod to understand the permissions. probably you do something like this : +w

Comment: If this is a permission then how other files can copied and directories created on the destination only `index.php` file could not copy on destination.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this permission issue, not in the new server but in the old server.

Please check owner:group of the index.php file in old server, so that your script can access and manipulate the origin file.

One more thing. Did you run the ftp transfer script, in the browser or in the command line?

This is very important, because one can run the script with APACHE user (www-data) and the other method run the script with your system user.

Comment: I am running ftp script on browser and the new server is 100% duplicate of old server i have check all rights of old and new servers there is no difference and strange only index.php file dose't copy all other files copied successfully.